# Kotlin: Warning:Classpath entry points to a non-existent location:

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting a warning every time when I build Project(Kotlin). This issue has begun After Creating sub-packages and using Room Database in Project(Kotlin).

I am unable to find my mistake or is there anything I have to add in gradle or in my project?
can anyone help me?

> Warning:Classpath entry points to a non-existent location:
>   /Users/app/src/debug/java
>   Warning:Classpath entry points to a non-existent location:
>   /Users/app/src/debug/kotlin
>   Warning:Classpath entry points to a non-existent location:
>   /Userapp/src/main/kotlin
>   Warning:Classpath entry points to a non-existent location:
>   /Users/app/build/generated/source/rs/debug

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This warning is a [Kotlin issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24716) which is fixed in Kotlin 1.2.51. Please update the version of Kotlin in your build.gradle.