# LeetCode error : Warning : Classpath entry points to a non-existent location:

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm practicing LeetCode with **Kotlin** for a few months. Every time I start a new question, I will make some test cases to make sure my understanding is correct to the question.
But today, somehow I see a weird error in LeetCode I have never seen before.

Here is Java code, I got the wrong answer.
[image]
Here is **Kotlin** code, I got the compile error.
[image]

I google the error log and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189149/kotlin-warningclasspath-entry-points-to-a-non-existent-location), and it tells me to update Gradle. But I can't, cause there is no *build.gradle* file in LeetCode.

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in the Leetcode's backend itself. Basically some files were missing in the docker image for Kotlin due to which it was happening. Leetcode has fixed the bug and replaced those docker images in their backend. So, it should be good now.

PS: I work at LeetCode.